# How to create attached property of type 'Type'?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i tried to create an attached property of type `Type` looks like:

```
   public static Type GetTargetType(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Type)obj.GetValue(TargetTypeProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTargetType(DependencyObject obj, Type value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TargetTypeProperty, value);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TargetType", typeof(Type), typeof(MyHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnTargetPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnTargetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // and here i want to use this type.
    }
```

and in the XAML Code:

```
// ...
     <myControl MyHelpeers:MyHelper.TargetType="{x:Type local:myclass}"/>
//...
```

i googled about this i find a way to create the type form string. but i disliked that way.
please help me.
thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the application--why would you want to do this?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You have an Attached Property of type `Type`, so why would you want to *create the `Type` from a `string`*? Just use the `Type` instance directly.

Comment: @user2588666, there are many reasons for doing that. I have used  Attached Properties of type `Type` to make my drag and drop functionality that is accessible from using Attached Properties type safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is in the event args, namely [`NewValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencypropertychangedeventargs.newvalue), just cast it to `Type`.

```
var type = (Type)e.NewValue;
```